# WPForms - Conditional Dropdown based on previous User Created Meta_Key Input Tag

Tags: php, wordpress, ultimate-member, wpforms

I'm using Ultimate Member for registration where users can input a Store Name when creating a new account.

That works well and when I go to their profile I can see that meta_key is there.

But later on the upload form, I need to add a dropdown where WPForms can read that meta_key and let the user choose from Store_Name meta_key when uploading something.

Can this be done in taxonomy? As this would be the best practice for this solution.

User creates a new Store name under "Stores" taxonomy and then he can access from the WPForms dropdown dynamic choices. The thing is that he would be able only to choose their submitted Store Name and no the other ones on the site.

I hope I'm being clear with my doubts.

Thanks in advance to this great community!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with relational db into post to user, and then using that relation logic into the dropdown.